# How does Combine work inside try-catch block?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I am trying to make a try-catch block with combine so I can execute certain function and re-execute main block again. I am doing something like this -

```
return urlSession.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
    .tryMap(verifyAPIResponse)
    .tryCatch { (error) -> AnyPublisher<(data: Data, response: URLResponse), URLError> in
        self.apiCallOne()
            .tryMap(\.apiResponse)
            .tryMap({ (response) in
            })
        return self.urlSession.dataTaskPublisher(for: request) //<<- DOES this execute after refreshToken or executes in parallel?
    }
    .tryMap(parseJson)
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

So my main concern here is -

1. Does the apiCallOne happen before it returns self.urlSession.dataTaskPublisher(for: request) or
2. Does the API call apiCallOne execute in background and self.urlSession.dataTaskPublisher(for: request) will be returned immediately? If so, I can I return after completion of apiCallOne?

Any pointers/help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions in the tryCatch closure execute in sequence just like any normal code. First `apiCallOne()` executes, then when it returns `tryMap(\.apiResponse)` executes then `tryMap({ response in })` executes then the `dataTaskPublisher(for:)` executes and the value from it is returned.

Keep in mind that `dataTaskPublisher(for:)` returns its Publisher immediately but starts doing work in the background. That work emits a value through the Publisher at some later time.

I expect that, based on the name of the function, `apiCallOne()` also returns immediately but starts doing work in the background and emits a value at some later time. The two tryMaps also return immediately but emit values when the Publisher they are called on emit a value.

All of this has the effect of the `apiCallOne()`s work happening at the same time as the `dataTaskPublisher(for:)`s work.

Comment: Thank you. With your help I was able to get to the end. And yes, it does execute synchronously as you said.